# Filter object by its sub array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following object:

[image]

Is it possible for me to filter it according to the subarray receipts?

Example: if the recipets position 1 has the user_id "11111" I display the entire object, otherwise I delete the entire object

I'm trying like this:

```
function get() {
  var allParkings = Parking.getParkings();
    allParkings.$loaded().then(function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(value, key) {
            console.log(value);
            value.receipts.forEach(function(rcpts, key) {
              if (rcpts.user_id === user.uid) {
              console.log('found');
            }
        })
    })
  })
}
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the delay, I used all the answers to create a solution.

```
function get() {
 var allParkings = Parking.getParkings();
 allParkings.$loaded().then(function(data) {
    vm.parkings = data;
    vm.parkings.forEach(function(value, key) {
    value.filteredReceipts = [];
    value.receipts.forEach(function(rcpts) {
        if (rcpts.user_id === user.uid) {
          value.filteredReceipts.push(rcpts);
        }
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: So what's your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below code. Basically use the `delete` operator to delete the object when the condition is met.

```
var obj = yourObject;

if(obj.receipts && obj.receipts.length > 2){
      if(obj.receipts[1].user_id !== "11111"){
           delete obj;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in function `find` which return a value if found, `null` otherwise.

```
data.forEach(function(value, key) {
    console.log(value);
    var found = value.receipts.find(function(rcpts) {
        return rcpts.user_id === user.uid;
    });
    if(found !== null)
        // found
        // console.log(value); goes here
    else
        // not found
        // delete value; goes here
})
```

The above code is the exact use case of `filter`. So you can do this instead:

```
data = data.filter(function(value) {
    var found = value.receipts.find(function(rcpts) {
        return rcpts.user_id === user.uid;
    });
    return found !== null;
});
// log the filtered elements
data.forEach( d => console.log(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either by writing 
[angular custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

or with [JavaSript array filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var newData = data.filter(function(item){
    if(item.recipets[1].user_id == '11111'){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
})
```